# Use Enum or String for a static factory method?

Tags: java, enums, design-patterns, factory, static-factory

Is it better to use `enum` or `String` to dispatch to the right object to create in a `static` factory method ?

Example with `String` :

```
public static Car createCar(String carName){
    if(carName.equals("Ferrari")){
        return new Ferrari();
    }
    else if(carName.equals("Porsche")){
        return new Porsche();
    }
    ....
}
```

Example with `enum` :

```
public static Car createCar(CarEnum carEnum){
    if(CarEnum.FERRARI.equals(carEnum)){
        return new Ferrari();
    }
    else if(CarEnum.PORSCHE.equals(carEnum)){
        return new Porsche();
    }
    ....
}
```

For now, according to me :

**Benefit of using `enum`** :

- Avoid that the user calls the factory with a non-treated `carName`.

**Drawback of using `Enum` :**

Increase dependencies because a change into `enum` (`FERRARI` becoming `ENZO_FERRARI` for instance) will require modification on client. However, with `String` we could redirect `Ferrari` to `Enzo Ferrari` instance without recompile client code. Of course, we could make the same thing for client using old `enum` values with a redirection of `FERRARI` to `ENZO-FERRARI` `enum` but for me it implies that `enum` would have to keep old values to make client compatible... no make sense for me.

I would like to know what are your opinions on this subject?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If, as you do in this case, you have a fixed number of acceptable arguments to a method, then it's best to enforce that constraint as best as you can on the clients of the method. In this case, accepting any old string would cause more failures than using an enum.

However, you might also consider, in a limited case like this, using named factory methods for each type of car: like createFerrari(), createPorsche() etc.

Comment: I prefer this explanation :) Thanks you and thanks to others who also answered well.

Answer (score 3):

Neither. Use an Enum and make the method an instance method of the Enum itself. No if's required.

Comment: @HosamAly I do not understand. With this approach the factory is already abstract in the base `Enum`, or at least it can be.

Comment: @EJP, Could you plz give provide code for your answer?

Answer (score 1):

I would use `Enums`; I don't like Strings used in this case. The advantage with enums is that you could switch over them (which will not work with strings) and you don't need to handle false input.

Answer (score 0):

Another benefit of the `enum` is that it let you use the `switch/case` syntax instead of infinite `if/else`.

Comment: Yes, but now with Java 7 we can switch with String ;)

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't add instance methods to enums. Today we saw strange unexpected behaviour when using static blocks in enums and refering to enums. Suddenly an enum instance was null!!!???
I would use an abstract factory pattern. This way you could use the same factory for two enum instances.
I would also use a hashmap to store the factories. This way you don't have the case or if's which add cyclic complexity.